# JSON object for just an integer

Tags: ruby, json

Silly question, but I'm unable to figure out..

I tried the following in Ruby:

```
irb(main):020:0> JSON.load('[1,2,3]').class
=> Array
```

This seems to work. While neither

```
JSON.load('1').class
```

nor this

```
JSON.load('{1}').class
```

works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd ask the guys who programmed the library. AFAIK, `1` isn't a valid JSON object, and neither is `{1}` but `1` is what the library itself generates for the fixnum 1.

You'd need to do: `{"number" : 1}` to be valid json. The bug is that

```
a != JSON.parse(JSON.generate(a))
```

Comment: humm I'dont exactly get it. The object returned by JSON.parse(JSON.generate(a)) should not be the same object as a, but it should have the identical content. In this case does == or != compare the contents (obj#hash) or the reference?

Comment: Ruby isn't Java! The semantics of `==` are different, it *may* compare references (Object.== does) but it's typically overridden to provide sematic comparison. Ruby has .equal? to check for identical objects.

Comment: From the https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627 JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans,
   and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays). So 1 is a valid JSON.

Comment: No it's not, as per the link you posted:

    `JSON-text = object / array`

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's a bug:

```
>> JSON.parse(1.to_json)
JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
     from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.1.3/lib/json/common.rb:122:in `initialize'
     from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.1.3/lib/json/common.rb:122:in `new'
     from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.1.3/lib/json/common.rb:122:in `parse'
     from (irb):7
```

I assume you're using this: (http://json.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 2):

**JSON only supporting objects is simply not true** -- json.org also does not suggest this imo. it was derived from javascript and thus especially strings and numbers are also valid JSON:

```js
var json_string = "1";
var p = eval('(' + json_string + ')');
console.log(p);
// => 1
typeof p
// => "number"
```

[`ActiveSupport::JSON`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/) properly understands raw value JSON:

```rb
require 'active_support/json'
p = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode '1'
# => 1
p.class
# => Fixnum
```

and so does [MultiJson](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json):

```rb
require 'multi_json'
p = MultiJson.load '1'
# => 1
p.class
# => Fixnum
```

so, as a2800276 mentioned, this must be a bug.

---

but as of this writing, ruby 2's JSON has `quirks_mode` [enabled by default](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#load_default_options) when using the `load` method.

```rb
require 'json'
p = JSON.load '1'
# => 1
p.class
# => Fixnum
```

Answer (score 1):

The first example is valid. The second two are not valid JSON data. go to [json.org](http://json.org) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As said only arrays and objects are allowed at the top level of JSON.

Maybe wrapping your values in an array will solve your problem.

```
def set( value ); @data = [value].to_json; end
def get; JSON.parse( @data )[0]; end
```

Answer (score 0):

**From the very basics of what JSON is:**

- Data types in JSON can be:

  1. Number
  2. String
  3. Json Object  ... (and some more)

[Reference to see complete list of Json data types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm)

- Now any Json data has to be encapsulated in 'Json Object' at the top level.
- To understand why is this so, you can see that without a Json Object at the top level, everything would be loose and you could only have only one of the data type in the whole of Json. i.e. Either a number, a string, a array, a null value etc... but only one.
- 'Json Object' type has a fixed format of 'key' : 'value' pair.
- You cannot store just the value. Thus you cannot have something like {1}.
  You need to put in the correct format, i.e. 'key' : 'value' pair.